# How does npm verify packages and how to verify npm/node installation packages between machines?

Tags: node.js, linux, npm

Where in the npm code does it verify the packages against a checksum? Also is it possible to verify one machine's installation of node and packages vs another machine? As in, is it possible to generate a bunch of checksums for a machine to compare with whatever's in the registry, and on a separate machine.

In npm, it seems to be using a tree library called the arborist to create a replica of the directory structure. On the other as a user i'd like to be able to validate, generate, checksums of the packages for the sake of provenance and verification. How do i go about doing this? And is it built into the package manager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where in the npm code does it verify the packages against a checksum?

Here: https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/04eb43f2b2a387987b61a7318908cf18f03d97e0/lib/utils/tar.js#L78-L80

```
  const integrity = await ssri.fromData(tarball, {
    algorithms: ['sha1', 'sha512'],
  })
```

> As in, is it possible to generate a bunch of checksums for a machine to compare with whatever's in the registry, and on a separate machine.

I'm not sure of the details of your use case but I believe it should be possible. Have a look at the [`fromData()` and other functions of the `ssri` module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssri#from-data) that `npm` uses to generate the integrity SHAs.

Note that `npm` generates the SHAs from tarballs (or from git SHAs if you are installing from `git` rather than the `npm` registry). So you'll need to package the modules up as tarballs. The [`npm pack`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-pack) command might come in handy.

Related (but not quite what you're looking for I don't think) would be the ["Verifying the PGP signature of a package from the npm public registry"](https://docs.npmjs.com/verifying-the-pgp-signature-for-a-package-from-the-npm-public-registry) article in the `npm` docs..

Comment: Is there a reason why they don't do the signed packages type of verification?

Comment: @placidchat Here's a Node.js maintainer on Twitter lamenting the same thing: https://twitter.com/matteocollina/status/1457755799019720714  And here's a former npm Inc. employee explaining why they never did it (across two tweets, here's the first one): https://twitter.com/isntitvacant/status/1457920522260340738

Comment: So basically what it's saying is since npm's inception in 2009, anyone could have slipped code in while in transit as long as whichever shasums that were downloaded from the same site matched? That's a lot of javascript

Comment: Here's another Node.js core maintainer chiming in too: https://twitter.com/jasnell/status/1458063957365714945